# Form Validation alert

Tags: javascript

I have written a form validation but the alert will not be for all the fields if we fill all the fields wrong.
Please check my file and tell me how can I do that.
I mean if we want to see the error after one error what should we do in my codes when I fill all them wrong it just error the first field that I filled it wrong.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Form Validation</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <script>
   function formvalid()
   {
    var a=document.forms["myform"]["firstname"].value;
    if (a.length<3)
     {
      alert("Write your name correctly");
      return false;
     }
    var a=document.forms["myform"]["firstname"].value;
    if(a==null||a=="")
     {
      alert("please fill the feald");
      return false;
     }
    
    var b=document.forms["myform"]["lastname"].value;
    if (b.length<2)
     {
      alert("Write your last name correctly");
      return false;
     }
    var b=document.forms["myform"]["lastname"].value;
    if(b==null||b=="")
     {
      alert("please fill the feald");
      return false;
     }
    var c=document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
    if(c==null||c=="")
     {
      alert("please fill the feald");
      return false;
     }
    var c=document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
    var at= c.indexOf("@");
    var dot=c.lastIndexOf(".");
    var dot2=c.indexOf(".");
    if(at<1||dot<2||dot+2>=c.length||at+2>=dot2||at+3>=dot2)
     {
      alert("Write your email correctly");
      return false;
     }
    var d=document.forms["myform"]["phone"].value;
    if(d==null||d=="")
     {
      alert("please fill the feald");
      return false;
     }
    var d=document.forms["myform"]["phone"].value;
    if(d.length>11)
     {
      alert("Write your phone number correctly");
      return false;
     }
   }
  </script>
  
  <form method="post" action="" onSubmit="formvalid()" name="myform">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="name">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="lastname">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="mobile">
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" value="click">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want all alerts to be shown, you shouldn't `return` anything inside your `if` blocks, the `return` stops the execution, the code after will not be executed. Here is the code without `return` and it works fine:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Form Validation</title>
 </head>

 <body>
  <script>
   function formvalid()
   {
    var a=document.forms["myform"]["firstname"].value;
    if (a.length<3)
     {
      alert("Write your name correctly");
     }
    var a=document.forms["myform"]["firstname"].value;
    if(a==null||a=="")
     {
      alert("please fill the feald");
     }
    
    var b=document.forms["myform"]["lastname"].value;
    if (b.length<2)
     {
      alert("Write your last name correctly");
     }
    var b=document.forms["myform"]["lastname"].value;
    if(b==null||b=="")
     {
      alert("please fill the feald");
     }
    var c=document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
    if(c==null||c=="")
     {
      alert("please fill the feald");
     }
    var c=document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
    var at= c.indexOf("@");
    var dot=c.lastIndexOf(".");
    var dot2=c.indexOf(".");
    if(at<1||dot<2||dot+2>=c.length||at+2>=dot2||at+3>=dot2)
     {
      alert("Write your email correctly");
     }
    var d=document.forms["myform"]["phone"].value;
    if(d==null||d=="")
     {
      alert("please fill the feald");
     }
    var d=document.forms["myform"]["phone"].value;
    if(d.length>11)
     {
      alert("Write your phone number correctly");
     }
   }
  </script>
  
  <form method="post" action="" onSubmit="formvalid()" name="myform">
   <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="name">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="lastname">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
   <br>
   <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="mobile">
   <br>
   <input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" value="click">
  </form>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, your function is almost ok, but you were not using conditions properly.

I have modified and tested it, it works perfect as your requirement.

Just replace your function with this  as below:

```js
function formvalid()
{
    var a=document.getElementById("firstname").value;
    var b=document.getElementById("lastname").value;
    var c=document.getElementById("email").value;
    var at= c.indexOf("@");
    var dot=c.lastIndexOf(".");
    var dot2=c.indexOf(".");
    var d=document.getElementById("phone").value;

    if (a.length > 0 && a.length < 3)
    {
        alert("Write your name correctly");
        return false;
    }

    else if(a==null||a=="")
    {
        alert("please fill the field");
        return false;
    }

    else if (b.length > 0 && b.length<2)
    {
        alert("Write your last name correctly");
        return false;
    }

    else if(b==null||b=="")
    {
        alert("please fill the field");
        return false;
    }

    else if(c==null||c=="")
    {
        alert("please fill the field");
        return false;
    }


    else if(at<1||dot<2||dot+2>=c.length||at+2>=dot2||at+3>=dot2)
    {
        alert("Write your email correctly");
        return false;
    }

    else if(d==null||d=="")
    {
        alert("please fill the field");
        return false;
    }

    else if(d.length>11)
    {
        alert("Write your phone number correctly");
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, Remove the return from each condition so that rest of the conditions can also execute.
Secondly, change the structure of conditions so that each field can get cross checked only once.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Form Validation</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <script>
            function formvalid()
            {
                var a=document.forms["myform"]["firstname"].value;
                if (a.length<3){
                    if(a==null||a==""){  
                        alert("please fill the feald");
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Write your name correctly");     
                }

                var b=document.forms["myform"]["lastname"].value;
                if (b.length<2){
                    if(b==null||b==""){
                        alert("please fill the feald");
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Write your last name correctly");
                }
                var c=document.forms["myform"]["email"].value;
                var at= c.indexOf("@");
                var dot=c.lastIndexOf(".");
                var dot2=c.indexOf(".");
                if(at<1||dot<2||dot+2>=c.length||at+2>=dot2||at+3>=dot2){
                    if(c==null||c==""){
                        alert("please fill the feald");
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Write your email correctly");
                }
                var d=document.forms["myform"]["phone"].value;
                if(d.length>11){
                    if(d==null||d==""){
                        alert("please fill the feald");
                    }
                    else
                        alert("Write your phone number correctly");
                }
            }
        </script>

        <form method="post" action="" onSubmit="formvalid()" name="myform">
            <input type="text" name="firstname" id="firstname" placeholder="name">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="lastname" id="lastname" placeholder="lastname">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="email" id="email" placeholder="email">
            <br>
            <input type="text" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="mobile">
            <br>
            <input type="submit" name="btn" id="btn" value="click">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```